# How to make a chain of signals in MQL5?

Tags: mql5, metatrader5

In my custom signal I want to collect results from other signals ( in `LongCondition()` and `ShortCondition()` ), then analyse them and return new, updated results of long and short conditions.

Other signals have to work in other timeframe periods.

How to include other signals into my main one?

Doing it through `AddFilter()` in an Expert Advisor is not an option, because of complex trade strategy logic.

Comment: this is not a MCVE question. so what should we help with?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are certain limitations an `MQL5` code cannot get easily crossed and get out from them. One is the construction of the QUOTE-event driven code execution, next is the Custom Indicator `iCustom()` engine in a just one, shared (!) thread, limited support for non-local timeframe(s)' data, the less in Strategy Tester, so I know, what you probably ask to have and need.

### Solution:

Having been within the last decade many times in the similar colliding requirements v/s the reality of the MetaTrader Terminal facilities, we decided to get outside of the box and went into Distributed System design.

MetaTrader Terminal code uses standard DLL-services to communicate with any external service needed, and the "outer" world can do and does pretty un-constrained and well all the things, the pre-wired MetaTrader Terminal did not get implemented since many years back - we simply do not use it for anything more, than to mediate ( yes, just mediate, not decide - i.e. just execute what the remote Master has commanded the platform to obey and submit ) the most simple Trading Instructions, whereas all the logic is completely MT4-free inside the external nodes ( having a full comfort of distributed python, non-blocking loggers, independent augmented GUI tools etc, etc. ).

This also helps ROI, we got less and less dependent on shocks from language / syntax / platform revisions.

This way you can create straight anything connected to the FX-market ( immense Neural Network predictor being the simplest example for such any thing )